# How to connect mangodb using nodejsin angular 8

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular8

I have created one website to sale organic food products in angular 8.Login and register form for user and admin Everything is done.I want to save these details in database also products order details. So how to connect mangodb database using nodejs and how to create table and how to push, update, delete, get the data from database.If anyone know please help.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to use **Mongodb** for your purpose. 
So using NodeJS, you can connect to the mongodb using mongoose driver, which helps you in easy connection.
You need to download the **mongoose** node module to your node application.
Using

> npm install mongoose

Then you can use below code to connect the database.

const mongoose=require('mongoose')

```
mongoose.connect('http://localhost:27017')
    .then(()=>{
    console.log("Connected to DB") })
   .catch((err)=>{
    console.log('Error') })
```

There after you need to create schema for both register and login forms, in order to save the data. you can use the below reference.

**For Register Schema**

```
    const mongoose=require('mongoose')
    const registerSchema=mongoose.Schema({
        Name: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: [true, 'FullName is required']
        },
        email:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
            required: [true, 'Email is required']
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required:true,
            required: [true, 'Password is required']
        },
})
```

**For Login Schema**

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
const loginSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type: String,
        unique:true,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        trim:true,
        required:true,
    }
})
```

I assumed both were in separate files.

Comment: Can you apply your concept here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-registration-login-example-xtzfxm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Yes, of Course. But what you have done is building up front-end in Angular. Now you need Back-end (mongoDb) to store your details. For that you need to build NodeJs application., and then Integrate it with your Angular. I suppose you to go through this link : https://bezkoder.com/angular-mongodb-node-express/

Comment: Can you look this:61596308

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/) to connect your app to the database.

Install mongoose

```
$ npm install mongoose
```

Connect to your database

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

**Note:** You need to setup your database somewhere first. You can either do it [locally](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community) or use [MongoDB atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas)

Create a schema

```
var kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});
```

This will automatically create a collection when connected. A collection is the equivalent of a table.

Create a model with the schema

```
var Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
```

Create a new document (equivalent to a row in sql, but hierarchical)

```
var fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' });
fluffy.save(function (err, fluffy) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(fluffy)
});
```